# Magento 2 Looking for configuration saved event

Tags: magento2, event-observer, cache

I'm trying to write something that automatically clears cache on magento, when user hits **Save**, on any pages under Backend / Stores / **Configuration**.

I'm only looking for the proper **event** to hook into for this function.

Thanks.

Edit: Or any tips on adding a Save And Clear button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config.php

Check **save** method. Following event dispatch:

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    "admin_system_config_changed_section_{$this->getSection()}",
    ['website' => $this->getWebsite(), 'store' => $this->getStore()]
);
```

Ex. For catalog section event should be:
**admin_system_config_changed_section_catalog**

Comment: If I use that event for clearing cache, is ```$this->_appConfig->reinit();``` (a few lines after) gonna interfere in any way ?

Comment: You can use $this->_appConfig->reinit() for clearing config cache. more detail vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php::clean